# Codeigniter : How to manage special character in multiple languages

Tags: php, codeigniter, special-characters

I'm currently working in a bilingual application in CodeIgniter and I need to manage special characters like colon (:).

In french, it's " : " (with spaces before and after) and in english, it's ":" (no spaces).

I thought about doing a label for the colon, like:

```
$lang['common.colon_separator'] = ' : ';
```

But in my view, it would be long to write something like this :

```
<?=lang('common.image').lang('common.colon_separator')?>
```

everytime that I need a colon.

I already thought about a helper or maybe using the inflector helper.

Is there anything else that I can do to manage this ?

Thx

Comment: I load language file with `$this->lang->load($file,$lang);` and recall label `<?=$this->lang->line('common.colon_separator') ?>`, but when special characters are different. Inflector helper is a good solution, and you could load a configuration file to create a general function.

Answer (score 0):

I would write a helper function for this, wrapping the `lang()` function to make the function name shorter. Add this to for example `application/helpers/my_language_helper.php`

```
function l($key, $element_id = null) {
    return = lang($key, $element_id);
}
```

Then make sure you autoload it and the original language helper in `application/config/autoload.php` (or manually load them in your controller).

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('language', 'my_language');
```

Add these to your language file.

```
$lang[':'] = ' : ';
$lang['common.image'] = 'Some image string';
```

Then all you need is `<?=l('common.image').l(':')?>`.